# how to stop local versions of jquery being loaded multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have been trying to find a way to stop my local version of Jquery and Jquery ui being loaded multiple times because of the pages I'm using are pulled in by Ajax and are reloading by Jquery every time.
The Jquery files I'm loading are

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
```

Comment: Show us how you are loading your Ajax

Comment: Don't output <script> tags in the HTML markup that's being returned to your AJAX request. When jQuery encounters a <script> tag in returned HTML it parses it out and loads the relevant `src` attribute into the actual page. When that happens, jQuery is overwriting itself with a new version of itself.

Comment: Alternatively, you can strip the `<script>` tags from the html with some regex before evaluating it. But really, you should just not have jquery in there (or any scripts if you can avoid it).

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how do you send the request. If page must be reloaded, let browser and server do theirs cashing job.

If you use ajax, load only a part of page, if you have some troubles. But you should post more code to show places with possible bugs...